# What is this plant with opposite leaves, dark stems and dark leaf venation?

Tags: identification, indoors, foliage

This is a full shade loving plant. I want to know its name and if it flowers.

[image]

Comment: Are you located in India?

Comment: yes. I am from India.

Answer (score 2):

## Justicia gendarussa (Acanthaceae)

This is an ornamental and medicinal plant.

Dr. Sharad Kambale, an Indian botanist, made the identification.  Dr. Suchandra Dutta, an Indian botanist, concurred the identification.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudopanax laetus or 5 finger.